# Reusable webdriver framework using SOLID design principles

Tags: c#, object-oriented, webdriver, cross-browser

I am trying to design some classes which I intent to use as a framework. I would like them to be compliant to SOLID design principles.

I had a basic structure and then I implemented Strategy design pattern and tried adding dependency injection as well.

Would like this to be reviewed so that I know if my understanding is correct or can still be made better.

```
public interface IBrowser
{
    IWebDriver GetWebDriver(string webDriverFolderPath);
}

public class EdgeBrowser : IBrowser
{
    public IWebDriver GetWebDriver(string webDriverFolderPath)
    {
        var options = new EdgeOptions()
        {
            PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager,
            UseInPrivateBrowsing = true
        };

        return new EdgeDriver(webDriverFolderPath, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    }
}

public class IEBrowser : IBrowser
{
    public IWebDriver GetWebDriver(string webDriverFolderPath)
    {
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
        {
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true
        };

        return new InternetExplorerDriver(webDriverFolderPath, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    }
}

public interface IConfiguration
{
    string GetConfiguration(string key);
}

public class AppSettingsConfiguration : IConfiguration
{
    public string GetConfiguration(string key)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].ToString();
    }
}

public class WebDriver
{
    private static Dictionary<Enums.Browsers, IBrowser> Browsers = new Dictionary<Enums.Browsers, IBrowser>();
    private static Dictionary<string, Enums.Browsers> BrowserMapper = new Dictionary<string, Enums.Browsers>();
    private static AppSettingsConfiguration _AppSettingsConfiguration;

    static WebDriver()
    {
        Browsers.Add(Enums.Browsers.Edge, new EdgeBrowser());
        Browsers.Add(Enums.Browsers.IE, new IEBrowser());
        Browsers.Add(Enums.Browsers.Chrome, new ChromeBrowser());
        Browsers.Add(Enums.Browsers.Firefox, new FirefoxBrowser());

        BrowserMapper.Add("Edge", Enums.Browsers.Edge);
        BrowserMapper.Add("IE", Enums.Browsers.IE);
        BrowserMapper.Add("Internet Explorer", Enums.Browsers.IE);
        BrowserMapper.Add("Chrome", Enums.Browsers.Chrome);
        BrowserMapper.Add("Firefox", Enums.Browsers.Firefox);
        BrowserMapper.Add("edge", Enums.Browsers.Edge);
        BrowserMapper.Add("ie", Enums.Browsers.IE);
        BrowserMapper.Add("internet explorer", Enums.Browsers.IE);
        BrowserMapper.Add("chrome", Enums.Browsers.Chrome);
        BrowserMapper.Add("firefox", Enums.Browsers.Firefox);
        BrowserMapper.Add("internetexplorer", Enums.Browsers.IE);
        BrowserMapper.Add("InternetExplorer", Enums.Browsers.IE);
    }

    public WebDriver(AppSettingsConfiguration appSettingsConfiguration)
    {
        _AppSettingsConfiguration = appSettingsConfiguration;
    }

    public IWebDriver GetWebDriver(string browser)
    {
        var browserName = BrowserMapper[browser];

        return Browsers[browserName].GetWebDriver(_AppSettingsConfiguration.GetConfiguration("WebDriverFolderPath"));
    }
}

public void Initialize()
{
    if (WebDriver == null)
    {
        WebDriver = new WebDriver(new AppSettingsConfiguration()).GetWebDriver(BaseData.Browser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `GetWebDriver()` could just use the `Browsers` enumeration to avoid having to create duplicate mappings like `"internetexplorer", "InternetExplorer", and  "internet explorer"`.

Comment: @Shelby115 thanks for the reply. Initialize method receives data read from an excel. So browser name can vary and I was not able to think about any other way to map user input to enums...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure that there is any good argument having these static fields, especially when it comes to unit testing the `WebDriver` class.

```
public class WebDriver
{
    private static Dictionary... // this
    private static Dictionary... // this
    private static AppSetting... // this

    static WebDriver() // this
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I would suggest you change those to `private readonly` fields instead.

and then we have this `Initialize()` method hanging out on it's own -- which means your code could not compile as is.

```
public class Foo // where is the class?
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        if (WebDriver == null)
        {
            WebDriver = new WebDriver(new AppSettingsConfiguration())
                .GetWebDriver(BaseData.Browser);
        }
    }
}
```

I highly would not recommend passing around the `AppSettingsConfiguration` class, when it seems like the only time you use it is to pull a string value by calling `_AppSettingsConfiguration.GetConfiguration("WebDriverFolderPath")`.

It would make more sense for you to handle reading your configuration somewhere else and not make the `WebDriver` responsible for handling that... (This actually breaks your "S" in the SOLID principle).

I would probably advise to consider refactoring it along these lines...

```
public enum Browsers { Unknown, Ie, Chrome, Edge, FireFox }

public class WebDriverFactory
{
    private readonly string _path;

    public WebDriverFactory(string path)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));
        // also, consider to a check that the path exists

        _path = path;
    }

    public IWebDriver Construct(Browsers browser)
    {
        switch (browser)
        {
            case Browser.Edge:
            {
                var options = new EdgeOptions()
                {
                    PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager,
                    UseInPrivateBrowsing = true
                };
                return new EdgeDriver(_path, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            }
            case.Unknown:
                throw new Exception("not a valid browser");
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```